# Suitable Won, Lost, Tied Icons

Tags: icons, tables

So I am using bootstrap glyphicons on my website site.

I am currently using glyphicon glyphicon-star for 'Won', glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty for 'Lost' and glyphicon glyphicon-fire for 'Tied'.

I am happy with the Won and Lost icons but the fire icons just looks out of place for tied and doesnt really make sense.

What would be the best icon to represent a Tie? I tried a half star but again it didnt look good.

Here is the list of icons I can use. http://getbootstrap.com/components/

*There are tooltips with the result on icon hover

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about

glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign

glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign

glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign

× for loser, 
✓ for winner, 
? for tie (winner unknown)

Answer (score 0):

Showing two pieces of rope tied together? An equal sign (=)?

Comment: I dont see something like that in http://getbootstrap.com/components/ unfortunately

Comment: Ahh I see; sorry, didn't fully read that question.

Comment: The two way arrow 'transfer' icon is pretty close to an = sign.